# Constant term of recursively defined polynomials related to the Lambert W function

Tags: special-functions, recurrence-relations

The Lambert $W$ function has the property that

$$
W'(x) = \frac{W(x)}{x[1+W(x)]},
$$

and using this one can show that its Taylor expansion about $x=a$ has the form

$$
W(x) = W(a) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{P_n[W(a)]}{n!\,[1+W(a)]^{2n-1}} \left(\frac{W(a)}{a}\right)^n (x-a)^n,
$$

where $(P_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of polynomials defined recursively by $P_1(x) = 1$ and

$$
\tag{$*$}
P_{n+1}(x) = \Bigl[1-(n+1)(3+x)\Bigr] P_n(x) + (1+x) P_n'(x).
$$

> Calculating the first 12 polynomials in the sequence I see that the constant term $P_n(0)$ is nonzero.  I would like to know that $P_n(0) \neq 0$ for all $n$, but I don't see how to show it.

It appears that the recurrence $(*)$ can be solved "explicitly" as a mess of sums and products, but this seems like trading one problem for a bigger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive the point $a$ to zero so that $W(a)$ is becoming small: $W(0) = 0$. Then, since $\frac{W(a)}{a} = \exp(-W(a))$ , $\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{W(a)}{a} = 1$. Now, consider Taylor expansion about $x=0$:
$$
    W(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} P_n(0)
$$
Comparing with the [well known](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog/06/01/01/0003/) series expansion for the $W(x)$ around the origin we find:
$$
    P_n(0) = (-n)^{n-1}
$$

Comment: Of course.  Nice observation :)