# Are there other power series for the Lambert W function than this one?

Tags: power-series, lambert-w

Are there other known power series for the Lambert W function, other than this one:

$$W(x) = x-x^2+\frac{3 x^3}{2}-\frac{8 x^4}{3}+\frac{125 x^5}{24}-\frac{54 x^6}{5}+\frac{16807 x^7}{720}-\frac{16384 x^8}{315}+\frac{531441 x^9}{4480}-\frac{156250 x^{10}}{567}+\frac{2357947691 x^{11}}{3628800}-\frac{2985984 x^{12}}{1925}+O\left(x^{13}\right)$$

```
Series[LambertW[x], {x, 0, 12}]
```

---

Edit 30.11.2013:

Is this a valid generalization to any z?

$$W(z) = \text{Log}[z]+\frac{(-2-\text{Log}[z]) (z-z \text{Log}[z])^2}{2 (1+\text{Log}[z]) (z+z \text{Log}[z])^2}+\frac{z-z \text{Log}[z]}{z+z \text{Log}[z]}+\frac{(z-z \text{Log}[z])^3 \left(9+8 \text{Log}[z]+2 \text{Log}[z]^2\right)}{6 (1+\text{Log}[z])^2 (z+z \text{Log}[z])^3}+\frac{(z-z \text{Log}[z])^4 \left(-64-79 \text{Log}[z]-36 \text{Log}[z]^2-6 \text{Log}[z]^3\right)}{24 (1+\text{Log}[z])^3 (z+z \text{Log}[z])^4}+\frac{(z-z \text{Log}[z])^5 \left(625+974 \text{Log}[z]+622 \text{Log}[z]^2+192 \text{Log}[z]^3+24 \text{Log}[z]^4\right)}{120 (1+\text{Log}[z])^4 (z+z \text{Log}[z])^5}+\frac{(z-z \text{Log}[z])^6 \left(-7776-14543 \text{Log}[z]-11758 \text{Log}[z]^2-5126 \text{Log}[z]^3-1200 \text{Log}[z]^4-120 \text{Log}[z]^5\right)}{720 (1+\text{Log}[z])^5 (z+z \text{Log}[z])^6}+...$$

Mathematica:

```
Clear[x, a, nn, b, z]
nn = 6;
a = Series[Exp[-x], {x, N[Log[z], 50], nn}];
b = Normal[InverseSeries[Series[x/a, {x, 0, nn}]]];
x = z;
b = b
z = Range[4]
N[b, 20]
```

---

These numbers appear to be found in the oeis: http://oeis.org/A042977 and the result is known.

Comment: This has a nice closed form, FYI: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}x^n$$

Comment: The Taylor series at some point for a function is unique.

Comment: I gave an expression for the Taylor series about any point in [my question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/316133/5531).

Comment: Possibly the different series expansions of Generalized Lambert W (Mezö, Castle) can be applied also for Lambert W.

Comment: The inverse series is a double sum of Stirling number of the first kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\P{\operatorname P}\def\W{\operatorname W}\def\E{\operatorname E}$
Concerning the first question, we use [Dirac $\delta(x)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/) and its [Legendre P$_v(x)$ representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LegendrePGeneral/23/02/0008/)

$$\frac1{\W(x+1)+1}=\int_a^b e^t\delta(t e^t-1-x)dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(n+\frac12\right)\P_n(x)\int_a^be^t\P_n(te^t-1)dt;0\le|ae^a|<|be^b|\le1,|x|\le1$$

Convergence based on $a,b$ is hard to determine. Now expand P$_n(y)$ with the [Pocchammer symbol $(x)_y$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pochhammer&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22pochhammer%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22SloppyFunction%22%7D):

$$\frac1{\W(x+1)+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\left(n+\frac12\right)\frac{(-1)^n(-n)_k(n+1)_k}{2^kk!^2}\P_n(x)\int_a^b e^{(k+1)}t^kdt$$

Therefore we use the [exponential integral E$_v(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=En+function)

$$\boxed{\W(x)=-\frac1{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left(n+\frac12\right)\frac{(-1)^n(-n)_k(n+1)_k}{2^kk!^2}\P_n(x-1)\left.\left[t^{k+1}\E_{-k}(-(k+1)t)\right]\right|_a^b
}-1}$$

Although slow, [it works](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%28lambertw%280.4%2B1%29%2B1%29%2CN%5BSum%5Bsum%5B%28n%2B1%2F2%29+LegendreP%5Bn%2C0.4%5D++%28-1%29%5En+%28+Pochhammer%5B-n%2C+k%5D+Pochhammer%5B1+%2B+n%2C+k%5D%29%2F%282%5Ek+k%21%5E2%29%28-0.8%5E%28k%2B1%29+En%28-k%2C-0.8-0.8k%29%2B0.1%5E%281%2Bk%29+En%28-k%2C-0.1-0.1k%29%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+50%7D%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C0%2C50%7D%5D%2C3%5D). A simpler idea uses the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cgamma%28a%2Cx%29), $a=0$:

$$\boxed{\W(x)=\frac1{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}\limits^n\left(n+\frac12\right)\frac{(-1)^n(-n)_k(n+1)_k}{2^kk!^2(-k-1)^{k+1}}\P_n(x-1)\gamma(k+1,-(k+1)b)}-1}$$

Graph of $\W(x)-(n=20$ approximation $)\approx0$:

[image]

Both series have interchangeable sums if $k$’s upper bound is $\infty$. For whatever reason, graphing any more terms is [chaotic](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%221%2F%28lambertw%28x%29%2B1%29-Sum%5Bsum%5B%28n%2B1%2F2%29+LegendreP%5Bn%2Cx-1%5D++%28-1%29%5En+%28+Pochhammer%5B-n%2C+k%5D+Pochhammer%5B1+%2B+n%2C+k%5D%29%2F%282%5Ek+k%21%5E2%29%28%28-1+-+k%29%5E%28-1+-+k%29+%28%5Cgamma%281+%2B+k%2C+-0.8+%281+%2B+k%29%29%29%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C22%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C22%7D%5D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%222%22) either due to the series or computational limits.

Comment: Are any simplifications possible? This is more experimental

Answer (score 1):

About the LambertW function :

From page 13 in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

[image]