# Lambert W function, W(x), representation for entire domain

Tags: power-series, special-functions, lambert-w

The Taylor series for the Lambert W function is $W_0(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-n)^{n-1}x^n}{n!},\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|<\frac{1}{e}\right\}$. Is there any exact closed form way to express $W(x)$ for $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\geq-\frac{1}{e}\right\}$? I am aware of Newton's method's approximation, $W(x)\approx\lim_{n\to\infty}w_n,w_{n+1}=\frac{xe^{-w_n}+(w_n)^2}{w_n+1}$, but this is not an exact value or a closed form, like the Taylor series.
Also, I came across these two questions, [Are there other power series for the Lambert W function than this one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584880/are-there-other-power-series-for-the-lambert-w-function-than-this-one) and [Question about Lambert W function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398078/question-about-lambert-w-function), with comments and answers that seem to answer my question, but I am lost on how they derived them, if they are actually valid, and what the solution's closed forms are. I apologize if I sound unreasonably ignorant in this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Series expansion is not generally regarded as "closed form". Strictly speaking, provided a proof of convergence, a Newton iteration or similar is as much of a "closed form" as a series expansion. Both provide a sequence which converges to the desired value.

Comment: @Ian, Sorry, I mixed up the mathematical meaning of closed form when I said it, as you mentioned. As for Newton's method, I learned that it was just an approximation for finding roots and does not actually give you an exact converging value like the Taylor series does. So, I am kind of confused as having a proof of convergence for it.

Comment: Proofs of convergence for Newton's method and other numerical methods are often specific to the problem in question, but we can still prove they work. For example, I can prove to you that the sequence $x_1=1$, $x_{k+1}=\frac{x_k}{2}+\frac{y}{2x_k}$ converges as $k \to \infty$ to $\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: @Ian, Oh, I see. You have been very helpful, and I wouldn't want to bother you anymore, so can you redirect me to a website that can help me understand how to prove convergence for your example and the example in my original question. Thank you.

Comment: @Emu: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/800070/21820) for a rigorous analysis of the Newton-Raphson approximation method. You can find more example applications of asymptotic analysis linked from my profile.